# how to get Twitter tweetbox without using deprecated @Anywhere

Tags: javascript, web-applications, twitter

I want to include a tweetbox on my site, but I don't want to use the [deprecated @Anywhere](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/anywhere/tweet-box) platform.  I can't seem to find an example of doing this without @Anywhere.  How can I embed a Twitter box on my site?

Answer (score 0):

My school personally uses [this](https://github.com/seaofclouds/tweet). Can't say if it is easier or harder to implement but they have some examples [here](http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/).

Comment: That looks like showing Tweets.  I want to show a textarea with a 'Tweet' button, prepopulated with some suggested Tweet text, so that a user can Tweet from my site.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood! I'll look for other options but so far from where I've been looking they have been pointing to the anywhere.js you mentioned. Any specific reason you don't want to use it? If it's just about implementation, I found a semi-decent tutorial about it [here](http://winkpress.com/tweet-box-lets-your-visitors-write-and-send-tweets-in-your-site/)

Comment: I don't want to use anywhere.js because they say on the page it's deprecated and going away entirely in December 2012.  I don't want to implement something now and have it only work for a month.